# Running rviz - couldn't find executable

Tags: rviz

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Dear ROS users,

as I would like to make use of rviz visualization tool but am new to Linux, I kindly ask you for help. As I type "rosrun rviz rviz" in the terminal window, I get the following message:

youbot@oleksandr-laptop:~$ rosrun rviz rviz

[rosrun] Couldn't find executable named rviz below /home/youbot/ros_stacks/rviz

[rosrun] Found the following, but they're either not files,

[rosrun] or not executable:

[rosrun]   /home/youbot/ros_stacks/rviz

[rosrun]   /home/youbot/ros_stacks/rviz/src/rviz

The contents of the folder /home/youbot/ros_stacks/rviz are as follows:
folders: bin, build, images, lib, ogre_media, scripts, src, test, ui

files (outside folders): CMakeLists.txt, mainpage.dox, manifest.xml

Hope for your reply!
P.S. I'm using Ubuntu 10.04

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9576/running-rviz---couldn%27t-find-executable/) by [ASMIK2011ROS](https://answers.ros.org/users/352/asmik2011ros/) on ROS Answers with karma: 62 on 2011-03-27

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

How did you do your installation? From SVN or from Ubuntu Packages, if you're using Ubuntu 10.04 it's advised to install from Ubuntu packages as explained [here](http://www.ros.org/wiki/diamondback/Installation/Ubuntu).
If you have an installation from svn, you need to build rviz first, you can do this by doing:

```
roscd rviz
rosmake --rosdep-install
```

Your username suggest you are doing this on a youbot platform, this is not advised as the youbot mini-itx is limited in resources, it's better to do your installation on a laptop and run only the roscore and drivers (you can find our drivers in kul-ros-pkg) on the youbot. By setting the ROS_MASTER_URI on your laptop you can still connect to the youbot and visualize all data on your laptop.

---

Originally posted by [KoenBuys](https://answers.ros.org/users/134/koenbuys/) with karma: 2314 on 2011-03-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3